# Set the properties in the configuration phase of a task in another task

Tags: gradle, build, properties, configuration, task

I have spent the last few hours trying to find a solution for my requirement, without luck:

I have a task that has to run some logic in a certain path:

```
task run(type: MyPlugin) {
    pathForPlugin = myPath //Defined as a property in another gradle file
}
```

I want to set the "pathForPlugin" property dynamically in another task because it has to be read from some configuration file.

```
task initPaths(type: PathFinder) {
     configurationFile = 'C:\\myConfig.conf'
}
```

The myConfig.conf would look like this:

```
pathForPlugin = 'C:\\Correct\\Path'
```

The problem is that "initPaths" has to run before the configuration phase of "run".
I have tried several approaches for this (GradleBuild task, dependsOn, Using Properties in the Plugin for "Lazy Configuration") but every approach only takes effect in the Execution phase leading to the "pathForPlugin" always staying at its default value.

Is there some way i can realize this or should i look for another solution outside of the gradle build?

Comment: Sorry, no time to reply with an example as usual, but please have w look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:inferred_task_dependencies). You need to define the path as an output property. Then in second task, configure it as an input. And it should work. Maybe I'll find some time to have a look at it later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem:

Instead of defining a task "initPaths" i directly used the java class "Pathfinder" in the build script:

```
import mypackage.PathFinder;

new PathFinder(project).run()
```

You only have to make sure that this part is above the definition of the task where the properties are used.

I admit this is a bit of a "hacky" solution but it works fine for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
ext {
    myPath //use it as a global variable that you can set and get from different gradle tasks and files
}

task firstTask {
    doLast {
        ext.myPath = "your path"
    }
}


task run(type: MyPlugin) {
   doFirst { //executed on runtime not on task definition
       pathForPlugin = ext.myPath //Defined as a property in another gradle file
   }
}

//example 2 - create run task dynamic
task initPath {
    doLast {
        tasks.create(name: "run", type: MyPlugin) {
             pathForPlugin = ext.myPath
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as i described the problem is that it has to run in the configuration phase, since "pathForPlugin" is a parameter for MyPlugin. Your example works perfectly fine since everything is run in the execution phase.

Comment: May be you can create the task dynamic on doLast method of initPaths task. Can be this a solution ?

Comment: That could've worked for my example yes, thank you! I chose to implement it the way i described in my answer since the real implementation behind it won't allow to create the tasks dynamically.